# Spring Data Rest: Excerpt as closed projection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot 2, with Spring Data JPA 2.0.9 and Data REST 3.0.9.

When using projections, or more importantly with Excerpts, I can see the entire Entity getting fetched and later wrapped with a dynamic proxy.

This is seems wasteful, since Spring Data JPA supports [Closed Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections.interfaces.closed), so we could only fetch the data needed. Since some of my entities are rather large and require joins, a closed projection would be preferable. Furthermore, Sprint Data also allows the use of Class-based projections.

Is there any way to make Spring Data REST use closed projections? Alternatively, is there some way to hook into the framework to supply my own implementation?

I've looked at `RepositoryEntityController.java`, but it looks like I would need to replace the `findAll(Pageable)` method, which is problematic for many reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is currently not possible. (Excerpt) Projections are applied after fetching the actual data. I don't know why it was designed this way - possibly bc. it supports several data stores, maybe some of them do not support selective fetching.

Either way, there is no way around this. If you always fetch a paged result, with for example 20 results, the impact might not be so big though.